# Efficiently Creating A Pandas DataFrame From A Numpy 3d array

Tags: numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Suppose we start with

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
```

How can this be efficiently be made into a pandas DataFrame equivalent to

```
import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 5, 7], 'c': [2, 4, 6, 8]})

   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  0  3  4
2  1  5  6
3  1  7  8
```

The idea is to have the `a` column have the index in the first dimension in the original array, and the rest of the columns be a vertical concatenation of the 2d arrays in the latter two dimensions in the original array.

(This is easy to do with loops; the question is how to do it without them.)

---

**Longer Example**

Using @Divakar's excellent suggestion:

```
>>> np.random.randint(0,9,(4,3,2))
array([[[0, 6],
    [6, 4],
    [3, 4]],

   [[5, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [6, 4]],

   [[8, 0],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 1]],

   [[2, 2],
    [0, 0],
    [6, 3]]])
```

Should be made to something like:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    'b': [0, 6, 3, 5, 1, 6, 8, 2, 3, 2, 0, 6], 
    'c': [6, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3]})
    a  b  c
0   0  0  6
1   0  6  4
2   0  3  4
3   1  5  1
4   1  1  3
5   1  6  4
6   2  8  0
7   2  2  3
8   2  3  1
9   3  2  2
10  3  0  0
11  3  6  3
```

Comment: Shouldn't we have `'b': [1, 3, 5, 7]` for that sample? Also, could you add another sample, like `a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,3,2))`, just to see what to expect when the dimensions have different lengths?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the excellent comment!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's one approach that does most of the processing on NumPy before finally putting it out as a DataFrame, like so -

```
m,n,r = a.shape
out_arr = np.column_stack((np.repeat(np.arange(m),n),a.reshape(m*n,-1)))
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out_arr)
```

If you precisely know that the number of columns would be `2`, such that we would have `b` and `c` as the last two columns and `a` as the first one, you can add column names like so -

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame(out_arr,columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Sample run -

```
>>> a
array([[[2, 0],
        [1, 7],
        [3, 8]],

       [[5, 0],
        [0, 7],
        [8, 0]],

       [[2, 5],
        [8, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[5, 3],
        [1, 6],
        [3, 2]]])
>>> out_df
    a  b  c
0   0  2  0
1   0  1  7
2   0  3  8
3   1  5  0
4   1  0  7
5   1  8  0
6   2  2  5
7   2  8  2
8   2  1  2
9   3  5  3
10  3  1  6
11  3  3  2
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked quite nicely. Although, I replaced m,n,r with x,y,z.

Comment: The best solution that I've found to pass 3d array to pandas dataFrame!!

Comment: Since the Panel Object was just removed in pandas v0.25.0 this should probably become the canonical answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel):

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
b=pd.Panel(rollaxis(a,2)).to_frame()
c=b.set_index(b.index.labels[0]).reset_index()
c.columns=list('abc')
```

then `a` is :

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]
```

`b` is :

```
             0  1
major minor      
0     0      1  2
      1      3  4
1     0      5  6
      1      7  8
```

and `c` is :

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  0  3  4
2  1  5  6
3  1  7  8
```

Comment: `Panel` has been deprecated, see answer below by @Divakar

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-Pandas solution without Panels.

To get a dataframe with MultiIndex, use `pd.concat`:

```py
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(arr) for arr in a], keys=np.arange(len(a)))
>>> df
     0  1
0 0  0  6
  1  6  4
  2  3  4
1 0  5  1
  1  1  3
  2  6  4
2 0  8  0
  1  2  3
  2  3  1
3 0  2  2
  1  0  0
  2  6  3
```

To convert it to the non-MultiIndex form provided in the question:

```py
>>> df.reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1).set_axis(['a','b','c'], axis=1)

    a  b  c
0   0  0  6
1   0  6  4
2   0  3  4
3   1  5  1
4   1  1  3
5   1  6  4
6   2  8  0
7   2  2  3
8   2  3  1
9   3  2  2
10  3  0  0
11  3  6  3
```