# Convert Numpy 3D array to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am quite new to Numpy and Python.

Two different shapes for an input array, it's either

- 24, 18, 2431
- 9, 17, 2431

How can I convert to a Pandas data frame without using `Panel` (It's removed from Pandas 0.25.0). The output should look something like

```
index | A | B | C

0 | A_value | B_value | C_value

1 | A_value | B_value | C_value

2 | A_value | B_value | C_value

3 | A_value | B_value | C_value

4 | A_value | B_value | C_value
```

Comment: The question is: how do you want to convert this: should it stop when the first array stops (so 18 rows for the first one, 9 for the second), or some sort of way to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235180/efficiently-creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-3d-array?rq=1

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The thing is we can get different combinations so the idea is to have 24 x 18 x 2431 = 1,050,192  number of items in the data frame.

Comment: @VinayHegde Thanks so much for pointing this out. The answer used in the link your provided uses Panel which is removed in Pandas 0.25.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently Creating A Pandas DataFrame From A Numpy 3d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235180/efficiently-creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-3d-array)

Comment: Is `(A, B, C)` supposed to be a shape? Because then your dataframe doesn't make sense, having dimension (sizes) as column header and values.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to indicate you can't or don't want to use `Panel` (since there are already two suggestions via a duplicate to use this).

Comment: 1,050,192 items in a DataFrame is a Series. Willem van Onsem's question effectively is, how do you want to reshape your 3D array into a 2D array? For example, will your DataFrame always have 2431 rows?

Comment: @00 I've edited the question to state that I should avoid `Panel`. My point for that `1,050,192` items is that I want to capture all the combinations that could make a row from this 3d array.

Comment: You need to give an example (for one or two small input arrays), of you want to achieve. "capture all the combinations that could make a row" is either a lot, or doesn't make sense.