# How to get a 3 dimensional array with the first two dimension named

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, structured-array

I'm working the numpy librairy in Python 3.
I would like to have a 3 dimensionnal array with the first two dimension named.

I have created a 3 dimensionnal array.
I want to access the array like this

```py
 my_3d_array["dim1_colnameX", "dim2_colnameX", 2:4]
```

I don't know if this is possible.

Here's what I've done:

```py
import numpy as np
my_3d_array = np.zeros((2, 3, 5))

my_dtype = np.dtype(XXXX)

my_3d_array= my_3d_array.dtype(my_dtype)

print(my_3d_array)
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but perhaps you could use ´enum.IntEnum` for indexing?

Comment: you should have a look at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/, it is like pandas but with more dimension

Comment: I didn't think of an enum, maybe I'll do this. Or maybe an array of list (to add a third dimension) but I think your idea is more elegant.
About xarray, I think it reveal that what I ask for is impossible... The inconvenient with xarray, is the code is for new people in python. I've already show them numpy and pandas, I don't think they'll like a third librairy for array.
Anyhow, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your output to look like?

You could transform your array into a pandas Dataframe and name the columns.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235180/efficiently-creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-3d-array), on how to create a dataframe out of a 3d np.array

After that you can name and rename the columns like this:

```py
#name
df.columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']

#rename
df.rename(columns={'column1': 'dim1_colnameX'}, inplace=True)
```

You can read about this [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_rename_multiple_columns/) or [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-rename)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It's not exactly what I want. Panda Dataframe are only with two dimensions, I want 3 dimension, that's why I go for Numpy ndarray.